301 Redirect via rewrite_rules_array (not .HTACCESS)
This is rule works so well.
add_action( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'rewrite_rules' );
function rewrite_rules( $rules ) {   
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules[ 'group/(.*)/?$' ] = 'index.php?pagename=test&group=$matches[1]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}

But now I have 2 URLs.

www.example.com/*kitty*/

www.example.com/*kitty*/*images*/


Now when I visit : www.example.com/*kitty*/
I want to be redirected to : www.example.com/*kitty*/*images*/
Important ! Redirected, not Rewritten
How can I do this ?
